# Converting printf-style logger with stack buffer to stringstream

Tags: c++, c, logging, variadic-functions

I currently have a logging solution that defines a macro like this:

```
#define MY_LOG(level, component, message, ...) { MyLog::Instance()->Log(level, component, message, __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); }
```

The const char* message parameter is using a printf like format, like "*My name is %s and I am %u.*"

The actual logging method I am using is that I declaring a *char buffer[2048]* variable on the stack and I am using vsnprintf to convert my va_list param, as defined in my message parameter, into my buffer. However, as I am often handling values that can be quite bigger than 2k, my buffer is always truncated so I thought about reworking the whole thing around stringstream which would be more flexible.

When implementing this solution, I encountered a problem with retrieving my va_args parameters from my list to use with the << operator... Is my only solution available is to parse the whole message parameter for % values and retrieve them by using va_arg with the type retrieved? I also need to push the text between my % values, so vsnprintf was really handy, as now I would need to split strings on % to push the previous text into my stringstream... Any hint or idea to help me out with this issue?

I can't use external libs for this and as I support platforms and compilers that may or may not support C++11, I can't entirely rely on new language features, but adding define to support both implementation is feasible. Also, as tons of traces are already in the current codebase, I can't really change the message format.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is your buffer truncated? Can't you allocate enough space?

Comment: I am limited on the stack size. Also, I would prefer to go away from C implementation. I thought that there must be a proper C++ way of doing it.

Comment: Of course you have limited stack. You should heap-allocate it anyway. BTW: What's level for? Deciding whether to log, or tagging the log?

Comment: level is an enum value to use whether to log or not.

Comment: There is already the solution, [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/). It's sorry that you can't use external libs :( Nevertheless, it may be helpful to look into it to write your own "Format".

Comment: @ikh the user says he can't **entirely** rely on new language features. While he can't accept almost anything, he is obviously willing to hear about any potential C++11 based solution. He is the one who tagged this question as c++11 in the first place... And by the way, stricly speaking vsnprintf becomes standard with C++11 (it was firstly introduced in C99 and visual studio is/was the last major compiler missing it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice not to try reimplementing vsnprintf on top of stringstream. If you intend to keep your logger front-end unchanged, you should keep vsnprintf!

First, you should rather guess the final size of the formatted string and allocate some buffer (using C++11 unique_ptr if you like it). You should not fear the allocation overhead as this is basically what stringstring would do under the hood.

Then, call vsnprintf with this buffer and test its returned value. This value (if positive) will give you the minimum size required to format the output string correctly not including the terminating null character. Knowing this you can choose to reallocate some buffer with the correct size and to call again vsnprintf with it.

Finally do whatever you have to do with this formatted string :
- construct an std::string
- write it somewhere (to a file?)
- just don't forget to release the memory (or use unique_ptr).

Note: Don't use an std::string as a buffer directly. Writing to the buffer returned by std::string::c_str() is undefined behavior.